# php header print tag pages

Tags: php, csv

I have this code to create a csv in php and after make possible the download:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array( //values...));

$rows = @mysql_query("SELECT //values from table");

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row );
```

But, after the download, when I open the file, what I see is the content of the page with the tags, in addition to the csv content.
How is possible to see all the content of the csv without the tags page?

thanks in advances

Comment: Which tags? post your output. And is this the whole script?

Comment: The csv contain the code of the page that call the function copied below:

Comment: If I got it right then, all you need to do is call this function and exit. Otherwise it will continue running the other page. Please post this part, where you're using this function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - I think the issue is that you are calling a function with the code you have posted when you have already outputted HTML (either intentionally or otherwise), when what you should do is link to a separate PHP Script containing your code, or not output before your code sample in called.

When you declare those headers in your code, you are telling the browser that the content is .csv but you are outputting this in the middle of HTML output (where likely HTML headers have already been sent due to some prior output).

Instead you can put your code in a separate PHP script and then create a link to it from other outputted HTML pages. This will mean that when your code is loaded the csv headers will be sent with the correct content only.

Comment: In your opinion to solve the matter, you suggest to introduce  another page, for instance page B, called from the link in the principal page A. Page B called the function explaned in the previous post...? Page B will be an empty page to avoid that the function download the content with the cs...

Comment: In your opinion to solve the matter, you suggest to introduce  another page, for instance page B, called from the link in the principal page A. Page B called the function explaned in the previous post...? Page B will be an empty page to avoid that the function download the content with the cs...  This is the code in the main page                                               

 <a href='welcomePage.php?dump=true'>
                Scarica elenco  </a>  |

if(isset($_GET["dump"])) {
 $obj->salvaCSV(); 
}


thanks in advance...

Comment: Get rid of the function - just have your code in the separate file and link to it (like as if it were a .csv file itself)